# Is there an algorithm to determine the best layout and font size for a specific screen?

Tags: margins, fontsize, algorithms

If I have a 4:3 7" tablet with a 200PPI screen (as an example), could you algorithmically make a TeX template that would be readable on the screen fullsize without zooming?

It would be great if there were a site where you could enter these dimensions and get a template for reference.

With so many different devices out there, I really think this would be useful.

Comment: I can share what I did with TeX Writer for iPad. First of all, you should add a custom paper size in articles.cls. Secondly, you will need to choose page crop parameters. If you are using dvipdfm, this is actually quite easy (See dvipdfm -h).

Comment: How would I determine font size for my pixel density? btw I'm using a Nexus 7.

Comment: This looks far too broad to me, and not entirely clear either. How do you determine 'best' layout?